# infinite loop in Hangman game in Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I am trying to build a simple Hangman game, but the following program is creating an infinite loop when the letter entered by the user is not part of the word to guess (it's printing `"*"` indefinitely). What is missing here? Any advice would be appreciated.

```
import re
import random

folder = open("datas.txt","r")
data = folder.read()

word_list = re.sub("[^\w]"," ", data).split()
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

letter_player = input('enter a letter pls:\n')

continue_game = False

masked_word = []
for letter in chosen_word:
masked_word.append("*")

found_letters = []

def guess_letter():
for letter in range(0,len(chosen_word)):
    if letter_player == chosen_word[letter]:
        found_letters.append(letter_player)
        masked_word[letter] = letter_player

    else:
        masked_word[letter] = '*'
        print(masked_word[letter])

return found_letters

str_found_letters = ''.join(found_letters)
print(str_found_letters)

if(str_found_letters != chosen_word):
    continue_game = True

while continue_game:
   guess_letter()
```

Comment: Inside while loop you only call one function. Inside this function you never touch `continue_game` which is your exit condition.

Comment: Please, fix your indentation.

Comment: `letter_player = input('enter a letter pls:\n')`
Shouldn't this line be inside the while loop?

Comment: The indent looks wrong. It is always helpful, to use pep8 on the code ;-) you only check continue_game against any input result once, after that the while happily executes guess_letter() based on always the same guess.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'll check it. The indentation is wrong obviously...

Comment: Also it will happily in guess_letter always overwrite previously correct letters with an asterisk (*) which will give endless joy ;-) I have an answer at hand, you might try to deepen your Python skills with, but please reformat the code correctly in the question and maybe even show a first try to read the input in the loop ... then I will happily provide an answer ...

Answer (score 1):

As there are others answering, why not hand out another try, from where the OP could continue? So here another version fixing also the overwrite error of previous found letters in subsequent iterations.Note also, that the append of letters found in a list may be what one wants, or maybe not, as the `o` in `foo` would be appended twice.

## # Python 3/2, imports and a literal:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import random

MASK_CHAR = '*'
```

### # Read words from file and select randomly:

```
def read_game_data(source="datas.txt"):
    """Randomly select a word from source data."""

    with open(source, "r") as f_data:
        return random.choice(re.sub("[^\w]", " ", f_data.read()).split())
```

### # Build sequences (here lists) of letters that constitute a word or "mask"

```
def build_word_seq(a_word, a_mask=None):
    return [letter if not a_mask else a_mask for letter in a_word]
```

### # the core evaluation function (previously named guess_letter)

```
def evaluate_letter(chosen_word, masked_word, letter_player, found=None):
    if found is None:
        found = set()
    for pos in range(len(chosen_word)):
        if letter_player == chosen_word[pos]:
            found.add(letter_player)
            masked_word[pos] = letter_player
    return masked_word, found
```

### # The function that replaces the continue_game variable:

```
def not_ready(chosen_word, masked_word):
    """Evaluate."""
    return True if masked_word != chosen_word else False
```

### # Put the business in a main function, minimize globals:

```
def main():
    """Do the game."""
    chosen_word = build_word_seq(read_game_data())
    mask = build_word_seq(chosen_word, a_mask=MASK_CHAR)
    found_letters = set()
    while not_ready(chosen_word, mask):
        letter_player = input('enter a letter pls:\n')
        mask, found_letters = evaluate_letter(
            chosen_word, mask, letter_player, found_letters)
        print(''.join(mask))
        if found_letters:
            print("LettersFound: %s" % (sorted(found_letters),))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A typical run based on a datas.txt file with:

```
foo bar baz
yes
no
```

yields e.g:

```
$ python3 hangman_again_inf_loop.py 
enter a letter pls:
f
***
enter a letter pls:
y
***
enter a letter pls:
b
b**
LettersFound: ['b']
enter a letter pls:
a
ba*
LettersFound: ['a', 'b']
enter a letter pls:
r
bar
LettersFound: ['a', 'b', 'r']
```

The loop again may be infinite (if you do not guess right ;-)

For a hangman game, there should be some equivalent counting logic, where the guessing competes against a line by line drawn hangman ...

Above code still needs replacement of input() by raw_input() when python v2 is being used ... but the OP used print() without future import, thus it is plausible, a Python v3 solution is good nuff.

Happy hacking!

Comment: Great, it helped. You may well accept it then, so everyone can focus on other peoples questions - or your future one's ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So, the biggest issue was the scope of the continue_game variable. Since it was declared outside of the function. "while continue_game" always evaluates the same.

To fix, add `global continue_game` in the method definition.

below is code that will break out of the loop.  to test I created a datas.txt file with one word and with the current logic, you have to type the word in that order for the `str_found_letters != chosen_word` to hit the else condition

```
import re
import random

folder = open("datas.txt","r")
data = folder.read()

word_list = re.sub("[^\w]"," ", data).split()
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

found_letters = []
continue_game = True

masked_word = []
for letter in chosen_word:
    masked_word.append("*")

def guess_letter():

    global continue_game, chosen_word, found_letters, masked_word

    letter_player = raw_input('enter a letter pls: ')

    for letter in range(0,len(chosen_word)):
        if letter_player == chosen_word[letter]:
            found_letters.append(letter_player)
            masked_word[letter] = letter_player
        else:
            masked_word[letter] = '*'
            print(masked_word[letter])

    str_found_letters = ''.join(found_letters)
    print(str_found_letters)

    if(str_found_letters != chosen_word):
        continue_game = True
    else:
        continue_game = False

while continue_game:
   guess_letter()
```